# Where should this code live in MVC structure?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model, controller, modeling

I'm reading a lot and getting really mixed results.

Say I have code like this?

```
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);

if(strlen($name) > 0 & strlen($email) > 0)
{
   $u = new User();
   $u.name = $name;
   $u.email = $email;
   $u.validate();
}
```

Where should this code live? The code that actually checks the form to make sure it has actual values? I say Model, but then what if your form spans across multiple models?

I'm a bit confused and any help to clear it up would be appreciated.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524037/designing-service-layer-classes-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally for the complete separation of concerns:

The `Controller` should be collecting the `$_POST` array and passing it to the `Model`.

Then the `model` would do the processing such as trim and validating.

I would +1 that the Model contains business logic.

Answer (score 2):

the checks in the model layer should guarantee database integrity.  all those checks should live in your u.validate() method.

you may additionally add checks to your controller layer as an optimization or to drive some view action.

i would refactor this way.

controller code

```
   $u = new User();
   $u.name = $_POST['name'];
   $u.email = $_POST['email'];
   if ($u.validate() && $u.save()) {
       // success code
   } else {
       // fail 
   }
```

model code

```
class user {
...
function validate() {
   if (empty($this->name) || strlen($this->name) < 1)  return false;
   if (empty($this->name) || strlen($this-email) < 1)  return false;
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this into `model` section, because model contains business logics..

**[Reference](http://whackylabs.com/blog/?p=367)**

Comment: Agree with model, but not about *model contains business logic*.

Comment: Even the form validation part? That simply checks to make sure the form has values? So you could then pass the $_POST array to the model?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great article that goes far to explaining MVC within PHP
[Oreilly](http://oreilly.com/php/archive/mvc-intro.html) the answers above are correct but in order for you to truly use MVC a certain amount of understanding about why each part goes where it goes is required hopefully this article will push you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are validating data before saving (e.g. email, name), then I vote Model.

Your MVC framework *should* be able to validate each Model's data.

In the end, MVC is an architecture. There is no definitive pattern. So it's up to you. A lot of the time consistency wins out. That is to say, if you want to put it in the controller instead of the model, do it throughout your code.