# What should the service layer of an MVC web application look like?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, service-layer

I have been reading about how to make my controllers clean and simple by moving business logic into a service layer. The problem I am encountering is that if I:

- Align the service layer towards models e.g. UserService, AuthenticationService, then that reduces redundancy but it also assumes that each method of the UserService e.g. update() is going to be used in the same way but business logic as we know is different in different parts of the application. Methods that serve multiple scenarios are usually dirty because if 3 different parts of the application use the same method then you have to satisfy all 3 parts.
- Align the service layer to reflect the controllers and their methods. This way has the potential to increase redundancy but it also makes it so you don't  build single golden bullet methods that are supposed to encompass any scenario they're needed.

I have shown 2 examples below:

Reflecting models

```
class UserController extends Controller {
     public function update(Request $request){

          // Load user service and create history

          $user_service = new UserService();
          $user_service->update($request);

          // Load user history service and create history

          $user_history_service = new UserHistoryService();
          $user_history_service->createHistory($request);

          // json response with success

          return response()->json([]);

     }
}
```

Reflecting controllers

```
class UserController extends Controller {
     public function update(Request $request){

          // Load user controller service, update user and create history
          $service = new UserControllerService();
          $service->updateUser($request);
          $service->createHistory($request);

          // return json response with success

          return response()->json([]);

     }
}
```

The 2 ways I have identified are just what I have been gathering from reading and also a bit of my own thinking. Which way scales properly and I guess has the least sacrifice?

Comment: Check out [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524037/designing-service-layer-classes-in-php?rq=1)